# Using auth0 and following their guide, however a token is not set and I am not redirected to the home page

Tags: javascript, authentication, reactjs, auth0

I'm following the tutorial on auth0's site for setting up a custom login on a react SPA (https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/02-custom-login).

I've followed their guide and set up my index.js and login/index.jsx.  However, when I click login, I can see that the request goes through successfully because on my dashboard I can see the # of logins increase.

[image]

However, in my app I get no errors and no token is set, and I still cannot go to `localhost:3000/home` which requires authentication.

Comment: When you say no token is set, is that in your LocalStorage? Also, did you use [the seed project](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-sample/tree/master/02-Custom-Login) or just follow the steps in an existing application?

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the reply.  Actually I managed to make it work, but the issue was that in the react getting started tutorial on Auth0, specifically for the custom login, they were using a parseAuth() in the onEnter when the request is made to login, and the #auth_token=token is returned in the url.  I ended up just checking if there's a hash in the URL that equals #auth_token and use that and set it in localstorage.